# How to query for "lightweight" vertex subtypes?

Tags: orientdb

Like lightweight edges, it seems like when a new vertex subtype is added to the schema then it is "invisible" until it has a concrete instance, ie:

```
create class Invisible extends V
create property Invisible.name string
select distinct(@class) from V
```

will return 0 results until I

```
create vertex Invisible set name='Not invisible anymore'
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you don't create any instances of "Invisible", you can't have any instances on query. What's your goal? If you want to access to the schema try with `select from metadata:schema`

Comment: @Lvca The goal is to be able to manage subtypes of V even if they have no concrete instance. 'metadata:schema' solves many different problems (not even necessarily related to V) that I have to tackle, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from ( select expand(classes) from metadata:schema ) where superClass='V'
```

Thanks, Lvca